# Is it possible to detect if Magic Mouse/Trackpad is being touched?

Tags: macos, cocoa, mouseevent, quartz-graphics

Just wondering if there is a way to receive a callback in Cocoa if Magic Mouse or Trackpad is being touched by the user?

I looked into Quartz Events, but it seems I can only get callbacks if the mouse is moving or clicked etc.

Note that I want to receive a callback even if my app is not active. It's a background utility app. Also, it can't use private frameworks as it's going to be a Mac App Store app.

Answer (score 2):

You could use this code to trap the events: (create a new Cocoa application and put this in the application delegate)

```
NSEventMask eventMask = NSEventMaskGesture | NSEventMaskMagnify | NSEventMaskSwipe | NSEventMaskRotate | NSEventMaskBeginGesture | NSEventMaskEndGesture;

CGEventRef eventTapCallback(CGEventTapProxy proxy, CGEventType type, CGEventRef eventRef, void *userInfo) {
    NSEvent *event = [NSEvent eventWithCGEvent:eventRef];

    // only act for events which do match the mask
    if (eventMask & NSEventMaskFromType([event type])) {
        NSLog(@"eventTapCallback: [event type] = %ld", [event type]);
    }

    return [event CGEvent];
}

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    CFMachPortRef eventTap = CGEventTapCreate(kCGSessionEventTap, kCGHeadInsertEventTap, kCGEventTapOptionListenOnly, kCGEventMaskForAllEvents, eventTapCallback, nil);
    CFRunLoopAddSource(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), CFMachPortCreateRunLoopSource(kCFAllocatorDefault, eventTap, 0), kCFRunLoopCommonModes);
    CGEventTapEnable(eventTap, true);
}
```

but.. sandboxing will probably prevent you from  using `CGEventTapCreate` because by nature, it allows an application to listen to the whole event system, which is not very secure. If not using the sandboxing is acceptable to you, then `eventTapCallback` is called when a new touch is made on the touchpad.

Comment: Sandboxed applications can do this as well, they need to be added in System Preferences (under security / privacy) allow Accessibility access.