# How to detect four fingered tap on mac trackpad?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am a beginning mac developer, and I'm looking to develop an app that detects a four fingered tap on the track pad. I have code that triggers a callback on a trackpad event based on the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9833522/is-it-possible-to-detect-if-magic-mouse-trackpad-is-being-touched). How would I specifically modify it to detect a four fingered tap?

Comment: If the events are caught, insert a breakpoint into your code, perform a four-finger tap, and look at what data the corresponding event contains. Low-level stuff like this, that you aren't really supposed to use, is often easily enough reverse engineered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the view in which you want to detect touch events, override:

```
- (void)touchesBeganWithEvent:(NSEvent *)event {
    NSSet *touches = [event touchesMatchingPhase:NSTouchPhaseTouching inView:self];
    if (touches.count == 4) 
        NSLog(@"4 finger touch detected");
}
```

Remember to enable the view to receive touch events with:

```
[self setAcceptsTouchEvents:YES]
```

Comment: Any ideas why I not get the callback despite calling `[self setAcceptsTouchEvents:YES];` and `[self setAllowedTouchTypes:(NSTouchTypeMaskDirect | NSTouchTypeMaskIndirect)];`..? (See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50464494/how-to-receive-rotation-gesture-on-macos-magic-mouse-or-trackpad).

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3** Version

In the view in which you want to detect touch events, override:

```
override func touchesBegan(with event: NSEvent) {
    var touches = event.touches(matching: NSTouch.Phase.any, in: self.view)
    if(touches.count == 4){
        print("Four finger touch detected")
    }
}
```

Remember to enable the view to receive touch events with:

```
self.view.acceptsTouchEvents = true
```